# How to aggregate/pivot MySQL data over timeline into matrix?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, aggregate

I have some sales figures over a timeline from n+ products:

```
DATE         PROD    SALES
2014-01-01   Alpha   1000
2014-01-01   Alpha   2000
2014-01-01   Beta    500
2014-01-03   Alpha   4000
2014-01-03   Beta    1500
2014-01-03   Gamma   700
```

a) I would like to display the sums per day as stacked bar-charts over time and need this format:

```
DATE         ALPHA   BETA   GAMMA
2014-01-01   3000    500    0
2014-01-03   4000    1500   700
```

b) Furthermore it would be nice to have all fully missing dates filled with 0

```
DATE         ALPHA   BETA   GAMMA
2014-01-01   3000    500    0
2014-01-02   0       0      0
2014-01-03   4000    1500   700
```

What's the best way to do this kind of aggregation in MySQL? With sub-queries?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "mysql pivot"

Comment: In your expected result, value of ALPHA is 2000 in the first record, right?

Comment: As an alternative to Kermit's suggestion, consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: NOTE: This is NOT a regular duplicate as (most) pivot questions are for a fixed set, but this one is asking for a FULLY DYNAMIC SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching for another 24h and thanks to the comments, here is a solution for a):

```
-- create the sum statement for all products
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('\n
  SUM(CASE WHEN prod="', prod , '" THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS ', prod)) 
INTO @sql
FROM productsales;
SELECT @sql;

-- embed the sum statement in the generic statement
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date, ', @sql, ' FROM productsales GROUP BY date');    
SELECT @sql;

-- execute as prepared statement
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This dynamically creates a SQL statement based on the existing products:

```
SELECT date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN prod="Alpha" THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS Alpha,
  SUM(CASE WHEN prod="Beta" THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS Beta,
  SUM(CASE WHEN prod="Gamma" THEN sales ELSE 0 END) AS Gamma 
FROM productsales GROUP BY date
```

It works in MySQL directly via command line (but not via phpMyAdmin):

```
+------------+-------+------+-------+
| date       | Alpha | Beta | Gamma |
+------------+-------+------+-------+
| 2014-01-01 |  3000 |  500 |     0 |
| 2014-01-03 |  4000 | 1500 |   700 |
+------------+-------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In case someone else wants to play with it, here is the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `productsales` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `prod` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `sales` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `productsales` (`date`, `prod`, `sales`) VALUES
('2014-01-01', 'Alpha', 1000),
('2014-01-01', 'Alpha', 2000),
('2014-01-01', 'Beta', 500),
('2014-01-03', 'Alpha', 4000),
('2014-01-03', 'Beta', 1500),
('2014-01-03', 'Gamma', 700);
```

Comment: You may need to increase the variable size limit: SET group_concat_max_len=4096;